# NPM initial start is failing?

Tags: angular, npm

I am tyring to start my angular project by doing ng s but its giving error because of some variables which are defined at window object.

```
var chart=window.Highcharts.chart()

Property 'Highcharts' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

When i modify any file it will compile successfully automatically.

I want to ignore those errors at intial start?

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: should be ```ng serve``` right ?

Comment: property 'Highcharts' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: @TonyNgo same on ng server also

Comment: @ravireddyupdate the code that using Window.Highcharts

Comment: @TonyNgo it didn't worked

Comment: @ravireddy I told you upload the code in your question that using Window.Highcharts for me to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the typings from HighCharts:

```
npm i -D @types/highcharts
```

Or update to version 7 of HighCharts which has `TypeScript` support included. With that version you can just import highcharts like this:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

If that doesn't work, you can also update the global window object declaration with your own properties. You should add this to either the `main.ts` or the `polyfills.ts` of your application:

```
declare global { interface Window { HighCharts: any; } }
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. but is there any approach to avoid erorrs by using npm beacuse in my application there are many scenarios like that

Comment: @ravireddy I expect you are not using highCharts 7. In that case running the `npm i -D @types/highcharts` should do the trick. Or maybe it won't, probably not. You are going to have to add the `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';` to all your files where you use it. Or, if you really don't want that, you can do the `declare global { interface Window { HighCharts: any; } }` in your `main.ts`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to import Highcharts as given below

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Once imported, you can invoke chart method as `Highcharts.chart`

```
  ngOnInit(){
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
  }
```

You don't need call `window.Highcharts`

Reference: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/highcharts-and-angular-7/